# Node.js developer get and post routes in console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get, console

Many of the projects I download from github have the post and get routes displayed in the console. However, I'm not sure how or where they are being created. I'm not positive but I think it has something to do with the 'bin/www' directory in these projects. I'm sure somebody has experienced this before.

[image: Console]

EDIT: 
prob didn't give enough info for this question, so heres the 'package.json' as that might help solve the question.

```
 {
  "name": "passport-mongo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "express-session": "~1.0.4",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "ejs": "*",
    "jade": "~1.3.0",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.12",
    "bcrypt-nodejs" : "*",
    "moment": "*",
    "path": "*",
    "mysql": "*",
    "nodemailer": "*",
    "moment": "*",
    "fs": "*",
    "express-myconnection": "*",
    "crypto": "*",
    "connect-flash" : "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think Express does that automatically.

Comment: I have other express applications that don't console.log anything..

Comment: No magic here - if you see requests printed out, it must be a middleware that does that.

Comment: I'm asuming it's some middleware as well, I'm just not sure what middleware is creating these console.log's. Although it seems quite popular on github

Answer (score 2):

The middleware that logs your requests in the console is called Morgan. Here is the url of the GitHub project

https://github.com/expressjs/morgan